# Google Maps: making SVG overlays clickable

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I’m trying to use google maps to display lines on a map and make those lines clickable.

These lines will be drawn in Illustrator, exported as SVG and then imported on to a google map using their Ground Overlay feature. This is all working ok.

What I’m unable to achieve is making just the line in the SVG clickable. At the moment, the entire SVG is clickable, including all the transparent background around it.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/95k49teu/21/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    initMap();
});

function initMap() {    
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18}
  });

    // GPS coordinates in degrees: A, A and B, B
  var imageBounds = {
    north: 40.773941, // A
    south: 40.712216, // B 
    east: -74.12544, // A
    west: -74.22655 // B
  };

  // Loop over all routes
  var myOverlay;
  myOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'http://setec-astro.website/line1.svg',
    imageBounds);
  myOverlay.setMap(map);

}
```

There is no click event implemented yet, but your mouse cursor will show you which area is clickable (a square area around the red line)

What’s the best way to go about making just the red line clickable? I’m not sure if the SVG markup should be changed, or if I can do this using just some javascript and the google maps API?

SVG looks to be just XML so if I could define some kind of logic to edit the SVG file on the PHP backend, that would be fine.

Comment: set everything you don't want to be clickable pointer-events="none"

Comment: Is there a reason you are using SVG rather than a google.maps.Polyline (or Polygon)?  Those support the addition of click listeners.  Do you have the geographic coordinates of that line?

Comment: @geocodezip Polygon lines work well: I draw the lines on a google map (I don't have the coordinates),  export a KML file and overlay that on the google map. The only problem is that when drawing them like this it's difficult to achieve the same fluidity of lines drawn in Illustrator. Over large distances you need hundreds or thousands of "dots" to achieve a smooth curves.

Comment: @RobertLongson where would I place this css rule?

Comment: In the SVG file

Comment: @RobertLongson inline css on the reverse selected portion of the line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try things and see.

Comment: @robert-longson, I couldn't make it work in the SVG file (at least in Chrome), are you sure it works in a Google Maps JavaScript API v3 GroundOverlay?