# Plot javascript-drawn SVG to map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg, leaflet

I'm currently working on having to plot custom-drawn SVGs on a map. I don't have much experience with drawing SVGs using javascript and much less experience drawing them on a map, so please bear with me.

The following snippet draws an SVG using javascript. The svg drawn is based on the 3 values that the function `makeLine` receives: *azimuth, radius, length*

How can I draw the point from the snippet in a map? Since several of these points would be plotted in a specific area (ie. a city) the the SVG would need to be resized to fit when zoomed-out. But if the map is zoomed in, then the point would also zoom in.

We currently use leaflet, but it can be any map (Google Maps, Microsoft, etc).

```js
        let svg = document.getElementById("icon");

// Add a "line" to the SVG, with a given azimuth, radius and length
function makeLine(azimuth, radius, length)
{
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  // Create an SVG <circle> element
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", length + ' ' + circumference);
  line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + azimuth + ")");
  // Add it to the <svg> element
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

let LEVEL1 = 93,
    LEVEL2 = 65,
    LEVEL3 = 37,
    LEVEL4 = 9;

makeLine(0,   LEVEL4, 15);
makeLine(120, LEVEL4, 15);
makeLine(240, LEVEL4, 15);

makeLine(310, LEVEL3, 50);
makeLine(180, LEVEL3, 55);

makeLine(290, LEVEL2, 95);

makeLine(300, LEVEL1, 110);
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        svg {
  width: 400px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 14;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>

</body>
```

Comment: With respect, your specific SVG is irrelevant to the question about placing images on a map. What the [example] needs to show is a map background, API version in use and what you've tried to get this to work.

Comment: That's the problem: I don't know how to draw the point in the map. I don't know how to combine the map and the SVG.

Comment: "_I don't know how to draw the point in the map._" - [Why is “I don't know how...” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593)
 - Start with the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#svgoverlay)

Comment: I've read the documentation, but as I explained, I don't know how to integrate the function and the map. It's a miracle I was able to draw the point.

Comment: Your `makeLine()` function adds content to an XML (SVG) document that is produced in the `<svg>` element. The documentation example does exactly the same thing but it does this dynamically. So, using the example, replace `svgElement.innerHTML =...` with calls to `makeLine()` where the function would append the lines to the example SVG document. It's that straight forward.  I'm sure someone will come along and write your solution for you. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps OverlayView: make only SVG clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327032/google-maps-overlayview-make-only-svg-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to:

> Since several of these points would be plotted in a specific area (ie.
> a city) the the SVG would need to be resized to fit when zoomed-out.
> But if the map is zoomed in, then the point would also zoom in.

You rather need a custom map marker using `L.divIcon({options});`.
divIcon markers will keep their size like default markers,
whereas svg overlays are scaled with your zoom level.

divIcon markers allow to set a custom html content.

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- map placeholder -->
<div id='map'></div>


<script>
// your svg markup 
let svgMarker = 
`<svg id="leafletMarkericon" class="leafletMarkericon" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="markerSvg" >
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="9" stroke-dasharray="15 56.548667764616276" transform="rotate(120)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="9" stroke-dasharray="15 56.548667764616276" transform="rotate(240)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="37" stroke-dasharray="50 232.4778563656447" transform="rotate(310)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="37" stroke-dasharray="55 232.4778563656447" transform="rotate(180)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="65" stroke-dasharray="95 408.4070449666731" transform="rotate(290)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="14" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" r="93" stroke-dasharray="110 584.3362335677015" transform="rotate(300)" transform-origin="50% 50%"></circle>
</symbol>
<use href="#markerSvg" class="markerSvg" stroke="#000" ></use>
</svg>`;


//initialize map
const centerLatLng = [52.520008, 13.404954];

const map = L.map("map").setView( centerLatLng, 13);
// set tile layer
var Esri_WorldGrayCanvas = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
    maxZoom: 16
});
Esri_WorldGrayCanvas.addTo(map);


// define custom marker
const customIconInline = L.divIcon({
    html: svgMarker,
    iconSize:     [50, 50],
    iconAnchor:   [25, 50], 
    className: "customIconInline"
});

// add custom marker to map
L.marker([52.529000, 13.404900 ], {icon: customIconInline}).addTo(map);

// add a svg overlay
var svgElement = document.createElement('div');
svgElement.classList.add('markerWrap');
svgElement.innerHTML = svgMarker;
var svgElementBounds = [ [ 52.525000, 13.405000 ], [ 52.528000, 13.402000 ] ];
L.svgOverlay(svgElement, svgElementBounds).addTo(map);

</script>
```

See also [leaflet: divicons](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon)